# Why is my simple Ajax call not working how I want?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a very simple homepage that goes like this:

```
 <h2>---Select your RuleType---</h2>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("LoadRules", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Rules" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x._SelectedItemId, Model._Items)
    <input type="submit" value="Load Rules" /> 
        <br />
}

<div id="Rules">
    @foreach (var rule in Model._Ruleset)
 {
     <tr>
        <div>test2</div>
        @Html.Partial("Rules", rule)
        </tr>
 }
</div>
```

It is a dropdown menu with several options, when one of the options is selected and you press the button it calls this method in my controller through ajax:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoadRules(RulesetModel model)
{
    model.LoadRules();
    return View(model);
}
```

I am returning the model so that the div with id="Rules" can be updated, as seen in the code my ajax has set its UpdateTargetID to that div. In that forloop I want to add several partial views for each rule in the model.

I checked my code and the model returned properly loads the rules and the array is not empty. But when I load nothing appears on the screen.

I've looked everywhere around for similar problems but can't find a good solution that works for me. I am pretty new to asp mvc so am I just missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a controller to server Ajax page as below -

```
public ActionResult Ajax()
{
    DDLModel model = new DDLModel();
    model._Items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    model._Items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "One", Value = "1" });
    model._Items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Two", Value = "2" });

    return View(model);
}
```

And the model is as follows -

```
public class DDLModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> _Items { get; set; }
    public string _SelectedItemId { get; set; }

    public List<RuleSetModel> rules { get; set; }
}

public class RuleSetModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

which loads following View -

```
@model Rami.Vemula.Dev.Mvc.Controllers.DDLModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ajax";
}

<h2>Ajax</h2>

<h2>---Select your RuleType---</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("LoadRules", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Rules" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x._SelectedItemId, Model._Items)
    <input type="submit" value="Load Rules" />
    <br />
}

<div id="Rules">
</div>
```

And when the submit button will be clicked it will hit the following controller action -

```
public ActionResult LoadRules(DDLModel model)
{
    model.rules = new List<RuleSetModel>();
    model.rules.Add(new RuleSetModel() { Name = "Rami"});
    model.rules.Add(new RuleSetModel() { Name = "Ramilu" });

    return PartialView("MyPartial", model);
}
```

As a result the following partial view will be returned -

```
@model Rami.Vemula.Dev.Mvc.Controllers.DDLModel

@{
    foreach (var item in Model.rules)
    {
        <div>
            @item.Name
    </div>
    }
}
```

And when we execute the code, we get the following view -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

1) Add another partial view for named as "rules"

```
<div id="Rules">
    @foreach (var rule in Model._Ruleset)
 {
     <tr>
        <div>test2</div>
        @Html.Partial("Rules", rule)
        </tr>
 }
</div>
```

2) From the action method "LoadRules" return the model to "rules" partial view

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoadRules(RulesetModel model)
{
    model.LoadRules();
    return View(model);
}


public ActionResult LoadRules(RulesetModel model)
{
 model.LoadRules();
 return PartialView("rules", model);
}
```

Comment: I dont fully understand your answer. What I tried was adding a second partial view and pass the list of rules to that, and in that partial view use my single-rule partial view. Which did result in it working but adding enourmous overhead and cpu overload that after loading 3x it basically crashed the website. So I dont think that is how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try using partial view.
Please let me know if you find any issues